# PAM, nsswitch and LDAP configuration

Tags: ldap, pam, nsswitch.conf

I have a technical and precise question about two type of configuration about LDAP, pam configuration files and nsswitch.conf.
Wich is the difference between the `passwd_compat` configuration and the `pam_list`?
I'm quite confused...thanks in advance.
Filippo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding your question you seem to be conflating two different things, which is probably leading to your confusion:

`pam_list` is an account authorization module - that is it lets you specify ways of determining if a user's account is "valid" on a given machine.  Refer to the man page for `pam_list` for more information.  You would use `pam_list` in a PAM configuration file in order to allow/deny specific users on specific hosts.
`pam_list` can be used with `allow` or `deny` files, and also has a "compat" option which makes it work the same way NIS traditionally does (+ and - lines in `/etc/passwd`).
You can refer to [the man page for `pam_list`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/OpenSolaris/5/pam_list/) for more information here.

> If you are using LDAP (pam_ldap or similar) there are "better" ways of doing the user authorization stuff - typically using LDAP groups or OUs to control access.
>   See the appropriate documentation for your LDAP PAM module for the specifics.

---

`passwd_compat` is a "pseudo-database" that appears in nsswitch.conf.  If you're using LDAP you would usually list LDAP as part of the `passwd` and `group` databases, and your LDAP-nsswitch interfacing module (nss_ldap or similar) would handle doing the LDAP lookup bits.  You could also set passwd_compat to point to `nis` or `ldap` as appropriate.  Typically this results in something like:

```
 passwd: compat
 passwd_compat files ldap
```

The man page for `nsswitch.conf` is a good source of information about this.  You may also find some insight in the O'Reilly book [Managing NFS and NIS](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9781565925106/) - about 10 years old (2nd Ed.) but still generally applicable.
I believe O'Reilly also has an LDAP book out but I'm not sure if it discusses anything about nsswitch or PAM...

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info voretaq! I did not know the difference between the two option, so I asked here. The big picture is: I'm trying to work with an LDAP who grants the authorization for some servers and it is now configured with the `passwd_compat` configuration. The customer had some problems and a third party told him to use `pam_list`. So now, I'm trying to understand the difference in order to have a clear image of the situation. Why use one instead of the other?

Comment: @Possa both are valid choices. pam_list requires additional infrastructure (the pam_list module, the allowed/denied list) that would need to be maintained on each machine, while using something like the `pam_groupdn` option in pam_ldap would centralize the list of allowed users on the LDAP server.  Centralizing makes it easier to change everything everywhere at the same time.